# Android webview autofill related crash

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, android-autofill-manager

I have been using android webview to load my PWA app. I have been getting lots of similar crashes on production app regarding webview autofill on crashlytics but unable to reproduce it. The stack trace is as follows:

```
       at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:169)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillValue.getListValue(AutofillValue.java:108)
       at Bw.a(Bw.java:49)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.autofill(WebViewChromium.java:7)
       at android.webkit.WebView.autofill(WebView.java:2837)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.autofill(AutofillManager.java:2188)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.access$2300(AutofillManager.java:160)
       at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager$AutofillManagerClient.lambda$autofill$1(AutofillManager.java:3154)
       at android.view.autofill.-$$Lambda$AutofillManager$AutofillManagerClient$1jAzMluMSJksx55SMUQn4BKB2Ng.run(-.java:8)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I have searched for these issues over the web but couldn't get anything useful. Please provide some pointers here.

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: @TynkHuynk - Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but this crash happens only for one user, so we decided to ignore it. Seems the user used some special tool/method to pick a drop-down item on the web page.